# check text background color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios

I am developing a Book application and in this there is a highlight text functionality. I have used UIWebview to load xHTML pages.

I have an JS by which I am applying background color to the selected text by below function.

```
    document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
```

Now when user selects that highlighted selection again I want to show option for remove highlight.

Is there any functionality in JavaScript by which I can get that selected text is highlighted or not?

Comment: Have you considered using a class instead that you can add and remove?

Comment: Martin,I have used http://jsfiddle.net/8mdX4/ to highlight the selected text..